# Issue with C++ Modules and OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, c++20, visual-studio-2022

I am having a compile issue with C++ Modules, OpenCV 4.5.5 in VS2022

I get C1001 "Internal Compiler Error"

Whats the best way to fix this?

ClassA.ixx:

```
module;
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "ClassB.h"
export module ClassA;

export class ClassA
{
public:
    cv::Mat myMat_; // <- This line fails to compile
    ClassB b_; // <- ok
};
```

main.cpp

```
import ClassA;

int main()
{
    ClassA a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "internal compiler error" means you need to talk to the makers of the compiler (microsoft). -- see if you can reduce the problem. OpenCV is an unwieldy dependency to reproduce a compiler bug.

Comment: Indeed... other libraries appear fine so theres something up with opencv maybe, or I am doing something wrong... 

The same code without using modules (regular .h) works fine

Comment: @aCuria: It's a compiler bug. There might be some snuffling around of code that you can do, but other than that, no.